# Cannot edit Cloud SQL instance properties

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I am about to install a new application that requires specific settings on the database such as changing the default connection details for the database (instance in my case). However, I am getting permission errors when I tried to save the changes. It appears the default sqlserver user does not have the permissions to make these changes. How can I get this done since my application requires it or this is the end of my Cloud SQL journey?

Thanks.

[Attached is the screenshot of what I was trying to edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKF6f.png)

[Screenshot of the error message I received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhXch.png)

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/users#superuser_restrictions) states you don't have acces to superuser permissions as Cloud SQL is a managed service. I don't see in the screenshot what you were trying to update but i guess it is only available to superuser.